# Node.js can't access lexical declaration 'x' before initialization and global variable problem

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

i'm having a problem with node.js app that i'm making. It's my first time using node.js so I knew there will be problems but so far I wasn't able to solve this one. I want to run a script after clicking an button on the site but I **get can't access lexical declaration 'log' before initialization** error and I think it is because I'm using global variable because the console is also displaying this error message **require is not defined**.

there's the code for script I export:

```
let login 
{
    login: Cat;
    haslo: 123;
}

function Logowanie(x, y){
    
        if (x == login.login && y == login.haslo){
            const zmianaTla = document.getElementById('overlay');
            const udanyLogin = document.getElementById('logon');
            zmianaTla.classList.remove('active');
            udanyLogin.remove();
        }
       else
            alert("Niepoprawny login lub haslo");
}
    

module.exports = new Logowanie;
```

the main script:

```
const log=require('./login.js');

x=document.getElementById('login').value;
y=document.getElementById('haslo').value; 

log(x, y)
```

And html part:

```
<script src="script.js"></script>
<div class="logon" id="logon">
     <h1>Logowanie</h1>
      <label for="Log"><b>Login</b></label>
       <input type="text" id="login" name="login" required>
            <label for="Haslo"><b>Hasło</b></label>
            <input type="password" id="haslo" name="haslo" required>
            <button type="submit" class="b1" onClick="log()"> Login </button>
    </div>
    <div class="active" id="overlay"></div>
```

I tried to fix it using solutions to the similar problesm other users had but they didn't work so I finally decided to ask for help myself.

EDIT: I forgot to mention im running the app using command line in Visual Code Studio. Here's the code for that:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require("path");
const http = require("http");
const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 3000;

app.listen(port, () => console.info('Listening on port 3000'));

app.use(express.static('public'))
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './public/css')))
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './public/img')))
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './public/js')))

app.get('',(req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './views/index.html'))
})
```

both scripts are in the same folder but in diffrent files (I'm using global variable so the `function Logowanie()` isn't visible during site inspection.

Comment: I think you are getting two errors here right? One is for `require` and one is for `log`. Please claritfy where main script is and where is the first code statement in

Comment: @Tushar Shani files for both scripts are in the same folder in diffrent files. There are 2 errors one for ```require``` and one for log() function that I exported.

Comment: Sweet those edits made it clear what was going on. I've edited my answer below to solve.

Comment: `let login { login: Cat; haslo: 123; }` is a syntax error. What did you mean there, an initialisation? If so, add `=` and remove the linebreak.

Comment: Why are you doing `new Logowanie;`? That function neither looks like a constructor, nor are you passing the expected arguments.

Answer (score 0):

OK I gotcha since that edit. Below are the changes you'll need to make to get this to work. Let me know if anything is unclear and I can help clarify.

You were on the right track, I think just the module import/exports and function binding were messing you up. BOL .

**useful docs:**

- [script type="module" docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules)
- [window object docs](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window.asp)
- [anonymous functions docs](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-anonymous-functions/) (used to bind `log` to `window`)

**login.js**

```js
// = sign was missing
let login = {
    // Cat is a String and needs quotes. Semicolons need to be commas in js object declarations
    login: "Cat",
    haslo: 123
}

function Logowanie(x,y){
    // should use === here not ==
    if (x === login.login && y === login.haslo) {
        // your code
    }
}

// Export your function from this file. This is ES6 module syntax supported in modern browsers. FYI you cannot use CommonJS style module.exports in a browser without Webpack or similar setup.
export default Logowanie;
```

**script.js**

```js
// Using ES6 module syntax to import your function. Note that you don't actually have to name it Logowanie as we used the default export.
import Logowanie from "./login.js";

// because we are using ES6 module syntax, you need to define the "log" function on the window object of the webpage. This is so the browser knows what to do if when we call log() onclick basically.
window.log = () => {
    let x = document.getElementById("login").value;
    let y = document.getElementById("haslo").value;

    // Logwanie function in login.js is expecting y to be an int due to === comparison.
    Logowanie(x, parseInt(y));
};
```

**index.html**

```html
<!-- the type="module" is needed to use ES6 module syntax -->
<script type="module" src="script.js"></script>

<!-- the rest of your HTML was fine I believe -->
```